# C# Cisco IP phone calling

Tags: c#

What I have is a cisco 7965 IP phone.

I'm simply trying to reference a SQL database, select the phone number from a column and send it to my phone.

I don't really need help with the SQL part, i need help sending the phone number to the phone.  If anybody has an example or a good place to start, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: What version of call manager are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco AXL programming

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/devguide/axl_prg/4_2_x/axlpg423.html

SOAP services for a Cisco Call Manager

Answer (score 0):

You can start querying the database of the call manager to which the phone is registered.
You can query for the **Numplan** table in the call manager database, once you have the information form the database it pretty easy to manipulate it.

Comment: A code sample would probably be a good idea to improve this post.